# Reporting Services Sorting by Date issue with TFS Report

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, tfs

Long time reader etc,

I've a TFS report that I want to alter the sorting on by date. The problem is the sort only seems to consider the day element and the rest isn't considered. For example, the following is happening:

1/7/2011
1/7/2011
1/7/2011
2/12/2010
3/03/2011
3/03/2011

I've looked for a way to specify the datatype on the box in the table but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised the field was being treated as text as the date in question isn't guaranteed to be there and replaced with an empty string if it wasn't.

Two steps have fixed the problem:

Added calculated field to dataset and wrapped an iif around to deal with missing dates as being way off in the future.

```
=CDate(IIf(IsDate(Fields!My_Date.Value), Fields!My_Date.Value, DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, 10,Now)))
```

This then forces the field to be treated as a date. I then added a sort on the group on this calculated field which isn't shown in the report and gives the impression that those items with a date get ordered and the rest are left to the other layers of sorting which is correct.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Guys, I would appreciate if you share any experience to get query sorted itself (without adding a separate column into the table in the design mode): I would like to build a graphics, and don't see any way to get graphic sorted by that calculated field. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a very efficient way!

I did it myself more complex
Group properties of the field you want to sort on
Sorting

expression:

```
=Datepart("yyyy",Fields!Datum.Value) & Datepart("m",Fields!Datum.Value) & Datepart("d",Fields!Datum.Value)
```

It will sort first on year, then on month, then on day